# Mongo get inverse of query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello I'm having trouble trying to understand how to write this query

My collection is a series of entries like this:

```
{
  id:1,
  name:"peter",
  number:3
 }
```

I want to be able to write a query which will return all items **except** for documents where the name='peter' **and** number=3

I know I can write something like:

```
db.test.find({$and:[{'name':'peter'},{'num':3}]})
```

to return all matching items, but is there any way of rewriting this query to return everything but the matching elements?

Comment: See docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a trick involving [$nor](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/query/nor/) with only one statement. Your only statement is then the original query. This works because `$nor` means that all conditions must be false; if you have only one condition, you get the negation.

So try:

```
db.test.find({$nor:[{$and:[{'name':'peter'},{'num':3}]}]})
```

I think this is nice because it's the negation of your original query exactly as it was

Comment: Hi Mario! How to build Compound index for $nor query. Like I have index for query and want to create the inverse index for $nor-query

Comment: @professrr I haven't used mongo in some years, but I don't think that you can really create an index for an arbitrary query: a compound index is an index on mulitple fields, correct? Not something you can do with any query, even with $and it wouldn't work (If I'm not wrong). You can also try to post this as a question here on SO if you want to try getting more details

Comment: @professrr however in this specific example, I believe that if you have a compunt index on both `name` and `num`, ti will probably be used both by the original query with `$and` and by its negation with `$nor`, because in the end we are checking equality or inequality on the indexed fields

Answer (score 4):

The **$not** operator requires a field to be bound to , but in this case it wont work. 
Basically I had to rethink my query, using [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> ¬(A^B) = ¬(A)V¬(B)

NOT (A AND B) = NOT(A) OR NOT(B)
so my query is

```
db.test.find({ $or:[{name:{$not:{$eq:'peter'}}},{num:{$not:{$eq:3}}}]});
```

Boolean algebra to the rescue!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the $ne operator to test for not equality:

```
find({$and: [{name: {$ne: peter}}, {num: {$ne: 2}}]})
```

Comment: the problem there is that it won't return any values with the name 'peter' regardless of the number and vise versa